# Check whether there is a break tag (<br>) in a textarea

Tags: javascript

I have searched for a solution when someone inputs their address to a form and submits without any breaking of the address (Melbourne, New Zealand). Then I found a quite simple JavaScript solution to search "," and break the line from that.

```js
function divide() {
  var txt;
  txt = document.getElementById('address').value;
  var text = txt.split(",");
  var str = text.join(',</br>');
  document.getElementById("address").value = str;
}
```

But this code will break even there is a break (when the user wants to update the entered details later), this code will break twice as it doesn't have any if condition to check whether there is a break tag. I want to know if there is a way of founding a break tag and how to include it in this code. I have tried many things, but couldn't find a solution. BTW I'm new to JavaScript.

Much appreciate your concern. Thank you.

Comment: Why not use separate fields and let the user separate them for you? That is the most common approach and one that users are very familiar with when filling out address details on the web

Comment: This is a task given by the office. They only put a text area for that. It's really better if we have two fields. But they gave something like this.

Comment: @JanithaTharaka HTML break elements should not even be in an input. Input fields are only for text, not markup.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl it is not for input field mate. It's for a textarea field

Comment: @JanithaTharaka your solution will also break for many address formats... for example in the U.S. the format has `city` comma `state` all on one line like "Los Angeles, CA" - your solution will make that format end up funky

Comment: It might be okay @maxshuty as they only need a break at the end of ,

I just want a method to check where there is a break or /n tag and do not execute the solution.

Comment: Textarea is an input field it's just not an `<input/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to replace the commas with line-breaks in a `<textarea>`, replace the commas with `\n` characters. There is no point to introducing `<br>` elements.

```js
const divide = (address) =>
  address.value = address.value.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, '\n');

document.querySelectorAll('.address').forEach(divide);
```

```html
<textarea class="address" rows="3" cols="72">foo,bar</textarea>
<textarea class="address" rows="3" cols="72">foo
bar</textarea>
```

Here is an example of setting saved text:

```js
const savedText = 'foo\nbar';
const breakText = text => text.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');

document.querySelector('.address').value = savedText;
document.querySelector('.address-css').textContent = savedText;
document.querySelector('.address-replace').innerHTML = breakText(savedText);
```

```css
.address-css {
  white-space: pre;
}

div[class^="address-"] {
  border: thin solid grey;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="address" rows="3" cols="72">foo,bar</textarea>
<div class="address-css"></div>
<div class="address-replace"></div>
```

Comment: This text is saving in the database. If the user updates, will this code again runs and break the line again mate?

Comment: @JanithaTharaka if you set a `<textarea>` with text containing a line-break (`\n`), yes the line break will be preserved. White-space is preserved within a standard `<textarea>`. If you are displaying the data elsewhere, you either need to set the whites-space of the element using CSS, or convert the line-breaks into `<br>` elements.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and the code. I will try my best to do that part.

Comment: @JanithaTharaka I added some examples of setting text as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't vote you as Im new to here. But I will vote you soon after I got 15. Thank you so much.